# Resin 4.0.47 com.caucho.server.webapp.WebApp.hasListener(ArrayList<?> listeners, Class<?> listenerClass) have a incorrect code

Tags: java, resin

I am using Resin 4.0.47, and i found a bug in the class
com.caucho.server.webapp.WebApp, the method

```
/**
   * Returns true if a listener with the given type exists.
   */

  public boolean hasListener(ArrayList<?> listeners, Class<?> listenerClass)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
      Object listener = _listeners.get(i);

      if (listener.getClass().equals(listenerClass)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

the line "Object listener = _listeners.get(i);", the variable should be listeners, not the _listeners, is not it?   how to fix it?

Comment: This question is borderline off-topic as you are basically asking for an external resource.  The question is likely to get closed.  Also, you could have easily answered this question yourself by visiting the Caucho site.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is might be considered a link-only answer, but it is the only possible answer to the OP's question.

If you are using the Pro version you should contact Caucho support through your established support contract.

If you are using the GPL version, then according to [this page](http://caucho.com/products/resin/faq#support) you can ask questions at the [Resin Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caucho-resin)